# How made sw-precache with network first?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-cache, service-worker, sw-precache

I have PWA web site with sw-precache with this sequence:

Reload the page

- The service worker should update the cache in the background When its
  done, you should see New or updated content is available. in the
  console The actual visible changes should not be visible until the
  next reload

Reload the page again

- The browser will use the new cache this time around The changes
  should be visible now! There shouldn't be any messages in the console

I need similar for this, but if file was updated - will be need visible in first load pages. Not after second load. Another (not updated) files - from cache.
This is possible? 
Because double reload for see new changes uncomfortable.

Answer (score 0):

you try use the [runtimeCaching](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache#runtime-caching) option to set up an appropriate URL pattern and strategy (networkFirst, cacheFirst, etc.) to match those requests.

```
"runtimeCaching": [{
   "urlPattern": "",
   "handler": "networkFirst"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

> global.toolbox.router.default = global.toolbox.networkFirst;  // for all routes

or

> global.toolbox.router.get('/assets/(.*)', global.toolbox.networkFirst); // for some particular routes